# Rails Ajax event on replaced DOM element

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ujs, rails-ujs

I have a simple Rails ujs app, with some remote links on the page.

```
<%= link_to 'Test', posts_path, remote: true, id: 'test' %>
```

In my js template, I replace this link with new one.

```
$('#test').html('<%= j link_to "Test", posts_path, remote: true, id: "test" %>')
```

At the same time I need to listen to ajax:success event:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.body.addEventListener("ajax:success", (event) => {
    # => Expected to be fired on all success ajax calls, no matter partial dom manipulations
  });
});
```

But the problem is that this event never fires. Because its target element get replaced.

How can I listen to ajax:success even if its target element is removed from dom?

My code has no practical sense, but its purpose is to demonstrate realworld problem in simple way.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't understand the use case, but maybe you can simply trigger an `ajax:success` event manually in your js template https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events. Not sure if that helps though.

Comment: if the new link will point to something static like posts_path, why not just recreate the link on the js file in the success event, you could write that into a function and call it after the success event to add the listener again to the new content avoiding the code duplication. I recently had a similar situation, but with the need of some dynamic data, ended up returning a json array for the link in the controller with the data(format.json) and manipulating the returned array on the js side to achieve the new content without rails

Comment: Are you using TurboLinks in this project? If so, your window onLoad listener would need to be rewritten for TurboLinks.

Comment: @Scott Swezey no turbolinks. The main issue is that ajax:success event is not bubbled after the target element is removed from DOM.

Comment: instead of listening for the ajax:success event could you trigger a custom event to listen for in your js template? `$('#test').html('<%= j link_to "Test", posts_path, remote: true, id: "test" %>').trigger('custom_event')`

Comment: although you may need to define that custom event separately. `var event = jQuery.Event( "custom_event" );` then pass that variable to `trigger()`

Answer (score 0):

When I've had remote links, to something like a posts show action, I would create a `show.html.erb` for the normal interactions, then also create a `show.js.erb` where there I would target the element I wanted changed/modyfied from the remote link and use the escape javascript method to replace the html there.
It would look something like `$('some element').html('<%= j render 'some_partial.html.erb'%>')`. Where `some_partial.html.erb` would be the partial of the element that's being replaced.

[Escape Javascript](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript)